# Android Thread.sleep after button click

Tags: java, android, user-interface

In android i have button which have ripple effect. But problem is there follows: When i click on button which call a method which runs some activity or load from database etc..., ripple effect sometimes freeze or is laggy. I have solved problem with Thread.sleep method. and works fine. But there i have seen discusion about Thread.sleep which blocks UI thread, and better usage is handler postDelayed. So when i use postDelayed then ripple lags anyways, but when i use Thread.spleep(some 200 ms) it work sure better instead  of postDelay. Its a good solution use Thread.Sleep ? Note: In background ar no other processes running. After click is only show dialog, or loading from db and show dialog, or loading some Intent with activity.

Any help apreciated. Thanks.

in onCreateView(...)

```
lNotificationsSettingsLayout.setOnClickListener(view1 -> OpenNotificationSettings());
```

method which will be called

```
private void OpenNotificationSettings()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, requireContext().getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, "task_reminder");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

xml code snippet:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lNotificationsSettingsLayout"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:text="@string/settingsItemNotifications"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:text="@string/settingsDescriptionNotifications"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingStart="20dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow"
                app:tint="@color/textColor" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If your ripple is freezing that means you're clogging up the main (UI thread). Post some code snippets so we see what and when you're deferring or what thread you're putting to sleep.

Comment: i have added some example code

Comment: in OpenNotificationSettings() will be Thread.Sleep(300) method. There looks originally without any sleeping methods.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Thread.sleep, you should consider using background threads or asynchronous tasks to perform time-consuming operations. In your case, when you call OpenNotificationSettings, you are starting an Intent which may involve activities or dialogs, and these operations should not be done on the UI thread.

Like this:

```
private void OpenNotificationSettings() {
    // Post a delayed action to run after 200ms
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_CHANNEL_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS);
            intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, requireContext().getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, "task_reminder");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }, 200); // Delay in ms
}
```

By using a Handler and postDelayed, you introduce a delay without freezing the UI thread. This should prevent the laggy ripple effect you were experiencing while ensuring a responsive user interface.

Comment: I have tried this same solution before but it not working in android 10, (still freeze and tested in emulator or physical devices [Maybe Android 10 bug ?]). When i have tried this in android 12,13 this works. But when i called some code for setting checkbox value only or show dialog box its works fine in android 10 too. But for this intent actions, or database operation its always lag